# IIS URL Rewrite Rule - IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I've the following functional ASP.NET URL: `www.netway.com/z/about.aspx` and I want to shorten this URL to as `www.netway.com/about`. When Users type `www.netway.com/about` in their browser, this will point to `www.netway.com/z/about.aspx`.

I've tried the following rewrite rule but it's not working:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Shorter URL">
                <match url="about" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="z/about.aspx" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Use this: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please look into following link.

It's showing a way to remove .aspx extensions.

http://forums.iis.net/p/1150350/2003891.aspx

You can also look into following also.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module